# Defining a condition number and termination criteria for Newton's method

Tags: newton-method, condition-number, roots, rootfinding

The condition number of function evaluation
$$
\mathrm{cond}(f,x) := \left| \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)} \right|
$$
is infinite at a root of $f$. Hence it is useless for rescaling a tolerance which defines an exit condition from Newton's method. For instance, naively, you would exit the Newton iteration
$$
x_{k+1} := x_{k} - f(x_{k})/f'(x_{k})
$$
when (say) $|f(x_{k+1})| < \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is (again, say) the double epsilon. However, even if $x^{*}$ is the correct floating point approximation of the root, we have no guarantee that $|f(x^{*})| < \epsilon$, due to the aformentioned ill-conditioning.

Is there a way to define a generalized condition number $\kappa(f, x)$ for Newton's method so that a reasonable termination condition can written in the form $|f(x_{k})| < \kappa(f, x_{k}) \epsilon$.

Note, even the proposed form of the termination condition is problematic, because the sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ is invariant under rescaling $f\mapsto \lambda f$, but the proposed form of the termination condition is not. Can we write a termination condition which is scale invariant?

The function which lead me to these questions was
$$
f(z) := 601080390z -185961388.136908293 + 141732493.98435241i
$$
Applying Newton's iteration to this leads to convergence to the true root in just three iterations starting with the guess of $i$, but $|f(z^{*})| \approx 3\times 10^{-8}$, which somehow feels "far from zero" in double precision, so my termination condition was never satisfied.

Comment: Any reasonable convergence criterion must be invariant to scaling of the function. A decent stopping criterion is therefore if $|f(x_k)| \le \varepsilon |f(x_0)|$ where $x_0$ is the starting point of the iteration. It's slightly that the stopping criterion now depends on the starting point, but because Newton's iteration converges so quickly close to the solution, this criterion in practice works pretty well.

Comment: There are two overlapping issues here: how to stop Newton's method correctly, and whether $f(x^*)$ can be expected to be small. The latter has much more to do with how exactly you define a "numerical root" of a function. You seem to expect that at a root, $|f(x^*)|<\epsilon$, but this isn't right at all and is generally not something you should rely on.

Comment: @Kirill: What is a sensible definition of numerical root?

Comment: It's a root if $f(x^\ast)$ is small compared to typical objects that have the units of $f$. If you measure weights in kilograms and $f(x)$ provides you with the weight of individual atoms, then $f(x^\ast)$ has to be exceedingly small for $x^\ast$ to be considered a root -- on the order of maybe $10^{-23} kg$. On the other hand, if $f(x)$ provides you with the mass of stars measured in kilograms, then you will be quite convinced that $x^\ast$ is a root if $f(x^\ast)$ is smaller than $10^{28}$ kg.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: I'm not sure this is actionable advice, unless the domain expert is also the one writing the root-finder. Most Newton solvers are black boxes.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Your original suggestion seems to me to be the only sensible option. Do you want to make it an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Normally, the value depends on the application. For example, I just checked Newton's method in SciPy and it uses a tolerance of $10^{-8}$ by default, and it's in the root not the function evaluation at that point.

Comment: @user14717 -- I made my comment into an answer. As for actionable: Yes, of course it is. The typical size of the function is given by $f(x_0)$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: A reasonable use case for Newton's method is to refine a root from a lower precision method. For instance, deflating a polynomial and then refining the root with the original. So I'm not convinced that $x_0$ is all that random; it depends on the use case. Combining your exit condition with nicoguaro's clustering of the sequence might be more reasonable.

Comment: @nicoguaro: I just got scipy.optimize.newton to tell me that the root of $x^2+1$ is zero. So clustering the roots is not sufficient.

Comment: I just tested it and it told me that it could not find a root. For me, it does not make sense to use that function to solve that problem since the initial point should be a float as expressed in the documentation.

Comment: @nicoguaro: My starting point was $x=1$. The point is to show that the termination condition of clustering the points tells you a root exists when it doesn't.

Comment: I can't reproduce your "error". This is what I get: ``RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 50 iterations, value is 2.1923521108433195``

Comment: @nicoguaro: What scipy and python version are you using? I'm on scipy1.1.0, python3.6.3.

Comment: @user14717 One definition is that for the given function $f$ and an approximate root $\tilde x$, $f(\tilde x+\delta)=0$ holds exactly for a small $|\delta|<\epsilon$. Another is that there is a "perturbation" of $f$ (e.g., an $\epsilon$-sized relative perturbation of your polynomial's coefficients) such as $f(\tilde x) + \delta f(\tilde x) = 0$. These are just the forward and backward stability concepts applied to this question. The problem with $|f(\tilde x)|<\epsilon$ is that it makes strong assumptions about the function (compare with $f(\tilde x+\delta x)=0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reasonable convergence criterion must be invariant to scaling of the function. A decent stopping criterion is therefore if $\|f(x_k)\|≤ \epsilon\|f(x_0)\|$ where $x_0$ is the starting point of the iteration. It's slightly annoying that the stopping criterion now depends on the starting point, but because Newton's iteration converges so quickly close to the solution, this criterion in practice works pretty well.